# joomla pass multiple variables with jquery and reassign them in php

Tags: php, ajax, joomla3.0

As the title say can please anyone tell me the syntax for joomla3 of how to pass multiple variables to the helper.php file and then reassign them to variables that I can use in the function?
This my js:

```
    var selectedData = {};
selectedData['author'] = $('#btnAuthorFilter').attr('value');
selectedData['category'] = $('#btnCategoryFilter').attr('value');
selectedData['keyword'] = $('#inpKeywordFilter').val();

request = {
                'option' : 'com_ajax',
                'module' : 'dc_blog',
                'method' : 'getFilterData',
                'data'   :  selectedData,
                // 'data' : { 'selectedData': JSON.stringify(selectedData) },
                'format' : 'raw'
                };
$.ajax({            
        data   : request,
        type   : 'post',
        success: function( response ) {
                $('#blogModule').html(response);
                }
        });
```

This my php (which doesn't work):

```
public static function getFilterDataAjax(){

    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $test  = $input->get("data");   return($test);
}
```

I'm able to pass just one variable and then use it, but not to pass multiple.
Does anyboy know the correct syntax?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$test = (array)$input->get('data', array(), 'array');
```

or this:

```
$test = $input->getArray(array('var1' => '', 'var2' => '', 'var3' => ''));
```

from [Joomla Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput#Getting_Multiple_Values)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. Thank you very much Nikos. I know it seems stupid but I've wasted a lot of time with this. Thanks again ;)

Comment: @Valina, great, if it helps you can also accept the answer. or comment for further clarifications

Comment: Basically I have just changed this line: $test  = $input->get("data");  with this: $test = (array)$input->get('data', array(), 'array'); and now I'm able to go through the array in the php by doing this $author = $test['author'] etc etc..

Comment: @Valina, good, note that if the variable is missing you will get an empty array instead (as an empty array is given as default value)